# python socket programming error

Tags: python, sockets

i got this error while running my function.

"socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use"

how can i close the address already in use and start new connection with port in python?

Answer (score 3):

These scenarios will raise error "[Errno 98] Address already in use" when you create a socket at certain port:

1. The port was't closed. When you created a socket, but forgot to close it, or annother program hold that.
2. You have close the socket(or kill the process), but the port stay at TIME_WAIT status in 2 MSL(about 2 minutes).

Try "netstat" command to view port usage

such as

> netstat  -na

or

> netstat -na |grep 54321

Answer (score 0):

Stop the program or the service which is the port which you are trying to use. Alternatively, for whatever program which you are trying to write, use a `PORT` number which is a sufficiently high number (> 1024 for sure) and is unused.

Comment: lets say i am using 54321 port.  how can i stop it? sock.close('54321') ?

Comment: If your program does not own that application running at the port, you cannot stop it. And sock.close() will shutdown the program. No need of giving port. Looks like a little reading of "Socket Programming Howto" would be helpful to you.